# Analytics for jquerymobile pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

we use ajax using jQm to access pages, but this isn't tracking page views understandable, how to set analytics to track the page hits?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the Analytics documentation, you should use event tracking to track ajax page loads :

> With ga.js, you would commonly apply Event Tracking to:
>
> Any Flash-driven element, like a Flash website, or a Flash Movie player
>
> **Embedded AJAX page elements**
>
> Page gadgets
>
> File downloads
>
> Load times for data

The setting up is described : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#SettingUpEventTracking